# Proof of transformations to find an approximate value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, problem-solving

[image]

I have no idea what this questions is asking, or how to go about solving.. can someone please help?

Answer:

[image]

Comment: It seems that the answer provides all the steps. What don't you understand ?

Comment: i have no idea what the question is even asking :S

Comment: They ask you to compute an approximate value of $x$ using Taylor first order expansion. SInce it is a cubic root, then take the corresponding function of $x$ and make the approximations.

Comment: ohhh yup so its differentiation?

Comment: The differentiation is required as said in the problem. Do you know Taylor expansion ?

Comment: I got that part.. im confused at the x^1/3 and -2/3.. where are they getting these numbers from?

Comment: What is the derivative of $x^n$ ? Replace then later $n$ by $1/3$.

Comment: but why did they start off with x^1/3 ....

Comment: Because they look for the cube root, that is to say x^(1/3)

Comment: You have a function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$, and you know that at $8$, the function value is easily computed exactly as $f(8)=8^{1/3}=2$. For values of $x$ near $8$, you expect the function value to be near $2$--but how near? This formula gives you the best possible approximation using numbers and formulas that are easier to compute with than trying to figure out exactly what (say) $8.06^{1/3}$ is. You can do this with pencil in paper, it's that much easier. You can't figure out the exact value so easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship "$f(x+h)\approx f(x) +hf'(x)$ for small h" is usually introduced long before the concept of Taylor series comes up. It is usually approached the first day of a calculus class as follows. Since we define $f'(x)$ as the limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $h\rightarrow 0$, we get an approximate value of $f'(x)$ by looking at the quotient for $h$ very close to $0$, that is, $f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ for small $h$. Multiplying both sides by $h$ and adding $f(x)$ to both sides, this gives the desired statement

$$f(x+h)\approx f(x) +hf'(x) \text{ for small }h$$

Here they are using $x=8$ and $h=0.06$. The formula becomes $f(8.06)\approx f(8) + 0.06f'(8)$, and using the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ (so that also $f'(x)=\frac13x^{-2/3}$) etc.